# convert blender to glb & fbx has Differences result in texture Discrepancy

Tags: texturing, uv, export, .fbx, gltf

I'm facing an issue with my Blender file, which features a single character with three materials: mouth, eyes, and general (body + skin). Each material consists of three nodes: Material Output, Principled BSDF, and Image Texture.

- In Blender, the preview looks good.
  [image]
- However, when I convert it to FBX for use in Mixamo, only a few areas have the correct textures, and the rest appears black (I've ensured the path mode is set to "Copy" or "Embed Textures" during export).
  [image]
- Similarly, when I convert it to GLTF (GLB file) for use in Godot, only a few areas have the correct textures, and the rest appears black.
  [image]
- When I open the FBX using the "3D Viewer" program, it looks fine.
  [image]
- However, when I open the GLTF (GLB file) using the "3D Viewer" program, it appears broken.
  [image]

here a preview capture that might help in troubleshooting this issue.

Could you please provide assistance in resolving this matter?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: It looks like you have some modifiers applied to your model.  Remember, FBX and glTF don't have any concept of Blender modifiers (other than Armature), so there's no way to store a modifier in an exported file.  Try applying them first.